# Giving Database path from textbox

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I want to create new MS Access  Database by Giving path from Textbox instead of prewritten path on Runtime in vb. net

Imports ADOX
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click




    Try
        Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()

        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=C:\Users\Anish Choudhary\Desktop\New folder\N.mdb;" & _
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")

        MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully")

        cat = Nothing


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Database already Exists")
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a textbox to get a folder path use the appropriate control provided by the NET Library. It is called [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)
TextBoxes are not very good for this kind of operation. The user could have a lot of problems typing a correct path, instead a FolderBrowserDialog in its simplicity allows to reach the correct path without manually typing anything

```
Dim fbd = New FolderBrowserDialog()
fbd.Description = "Select a folder for the new database"
fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = True
If fbd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Try
        Dim filePath =  Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, "N.mdb")
        Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & filePath & _
                    "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
        MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully")
        cat = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Database already Exists")
    End Try
End If
```

Comment: sir your code is giving error  in first line in try block that "'path'  is not declared. it may be in accessible due to its protection level."

Comment: The Path class is defined in the System.IO namespace then you need to add this line in the file that contains this code: _Imports System.IO_

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer to the textbox in your code.

Assumes your code is in the Form with the textbox

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
    Dim cat As Catalog = New Catalog()
    cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & txtFilePath & "N.mdb;" & _
                "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5")
    MessageBox.Show("Database Created Successfully")
    cat = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Database already Exists")
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I should say that none of this methods works. In the first one you are not allowed to change the signature of a standard event handler adding your own parameters, in the second one if the txtFilePath is a textbox then you should use the txtFilePath.Text property instead (and the concatenation of the mdb file could fail if the user forgets to type the final backslash)

Comment: Method 1 is not working when iam passing Textbox as Parameter but method 2 is fine